# Comparing arrays with comparison operator

Tags: c++, arrays

This is just a small question, more aimed at understanding the usage of arrays than at solving a difficult problem.

I currently have an array of four integers (Neighbors) that I'd like to compare against a set of other arrays (which don't exist anywhere else - I have no need to store them).  I want to know which of the four arrays Neighbors is identical to.  As somebody who doesn't know any better, my first attempt was to do this:

```
if (Neighbors == {1, 1, 0, 0})
{
    //code...
}
else if (Neighbors == {0, 1, 1, 0})
{
    //code...
}
else if (Neighbors == {0, 0, 1, 1})
{
    //code...
}
else if (Neighbors == {1, 0, 0, 1})
{
    //code...
}
```

As you can see, the order of the integers is important.  However, the above returned compiler errors about expecting primary expressions before curly-brace tokens.

So instead, I tried this:

```
int Sets[4][4] = { {1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1} };
if (Neighbors == Sets[0])
{
    //code...
}
else if (Neighbors == Sets[1])
{
    //code...
}
else if (Neighbors == Sets[2])
{
    //code...
}
else if (Neighbors == Sets[3])
{
    //code...
}
```

What happens here is that even when `Neighbors = {0, 1, 1, 0}` (for example), `Neighbors == Sets[1]` returns false.

Now, after doing this and wondering why, I remembered that the array variable is basically a pointer to the first element in a sequence.  Right?  So I think I get why the above code doesn't work - I'm comparing two memory addresses, rather than two arrays.  So instead I wrote this code, which works fine:

```
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 4; ++ii)
    {
        bool Same = true;
        for (int jj = 0; jj < 4; ++jj)
        {
            if (Neighbors[jj] != Set[ii][jj])
            {
                Same = false;
            }
        }

        if (Same == true)
        {
            //code...
        }
    }
```

What I want to know is whether there is a way to compare arrays like this without going through two for-loops.  It seems like something that ought to be simpler than this.  I know a for-loop isn't especially intensive when you've only got 4 values, but I still would have thought it'd be easier to determine whether two arrays contain identical information.  If each array is a contiguous block of memory, I would have thought you could just look at those two blocks and check whether they are identical (which is basically what the for-loops are doing, although that requires doing it manually).

So is there a way to compare the content of arrays directly, preferably with a single line of code?  If not, why not?  I'd like to understand the science behind this issue.

Comment: Just a tip here - you can add a `break;` statement after your line `Same = false;` this will speed up a little as once you know its false, why continue checking (unless you really want to) ???

Comment: That's true - I usually do that, but I forgot this time around, since it's such a small set of data.  Thanks for the reminder though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have tagged the question C++. Which means you should be using `std::vector`. It has overloaded [`operator==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) that does what you want (for two vectors).

You can also use [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) or [`std::lexicographical_compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) for anything you have iterators for, which includes primitive arrays.

Of course you can also overload the `operator==` for other things. Unfortunately you can't overload it for primitive arrays, because overloading operators is only allowed if at least one argument is a class (or struct) type. But you could override it to compare vector with array. Something like:

```
template<typename T, typename Alloc, size_t S>
bool operator==(std::vector<T, Alloc> v, const T (&a)[S])
{
    return v.size() == S && std::equal(v.begin(), v.end(), a);
}
```

(this takes reference to array not degraded to pointer to check it's declared size first and is therefore safe)

Of course all these methods have a loop hidden inside that compares the elements one by one. But you don't have to write it.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll look into that one as well.

Answer (score 4):

The C++iest way to do this is with [std::equal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) :

```
#include <algorithm>
```

With C++11:

```
if (std::equal(begin(Neighbors), end(Neighbors), begin(Sets[0]))
{ /* then they're equal */ }
```

With C++03:

```
if (std::equal(Neighbors, Neighbors + 4, Sets[0]))
{ /* then they're equal */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `memcmp` function. If arrays are equal it returns 0. Here is a description: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcmp/

Comment: The question is tagged C++. `memcmp` is grossly inappropriate in that language. Should use the typesafe `std::lexicographical_compare` instead.